# Spring not working correctly but no error message

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am currently working on a project using Spring Hibernate.

Normally, when I deploy and run my project using Tomcat, I would see in the console printing something similar to the picture below:

[image]

However, my current build doesn't show that Spring sign anymore.

The output I receive on the console is simply:

```
Connected to server
[2017-03-24 01:14:19,058] Artifact Gradle : com.enocom : jddp-112.112.112.war (exploded): Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-03-24 01:14:19,416] Artifact Gradle : com.enocom : jddp-112.112.112.war (exploded): Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-03-24 01:14:19,416] Artifact Gradle : com.enocom : jddp-112.112.112.war (exploded): Deploy took 358 milliseconds
24-Mar-2017 13:14:28.886 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager
24-Mar-2017 13:14:28.949 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager has finished in 63 ms
```

There is no error message, server is connected, and war file is deployed.  But why is the Spring sign gone and is the project running correctly?  What could be the cause to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Check the value of `spring.main.banner-mode` in the properties. You can print the property using `System.getProperty("prop")/System.env("prop")` or just by adding `Actuator` dependency to the `POM` you will be able to see all the properties in `/env` end point.

There are 3 possible values [from the documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html).

- console
- log
- off

Banner won't be printed if the value is `off`.

Easiest way would be to manually set the value to `console/log` and see if it's printed.

Comment: Good catch.  Don't know how the banner value was changed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed your `ApplicationLauncher` class (which contains `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) in your jar, so spring boot is not launched.

You can look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) to find an example on how spring bootstrapping works.